# Convert string vector to dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am working on a quick scraping project that involves grabbing historical NFL football data. Here is a quick glance of what my data looks like:

```
allgames_thisweek = c("Chicago Bears 21, Tampa Bay Buccaneers 9 -- Box Score", "Cleveland Browns 28, Cincinnati Bengals 20 -- Box Score", 
"Dallas Cowboys 26, Pittsburgh Steelers 9 -- Box Score", "Detroit Lions 31, Atlanta Falcons 28 (OT)  -- Box Score", 
"Green Bay Packers 16, Minnesota Vikings 10 -- Box Score", "Indianapolis Colts 45, Houston Oilers 21 -- Box Score", 
"Kansas City Chiefs 30, New Orleans Saints 17 -- Box Score", 
"Los Angeles Rams 14, Arizona Cardinals 12 -- Box Score", "Miami Dolphins 39, New England Patriots 35 -- Box Score", 
"New York Giants 28, Philadelphia Eagles 23 -- Box Score", "New York Jets 23, Buffalo Bills 3 -- Box Score", 
"San Diego Chargers 37, Denver Broncos 34 -- Box Score", "San Francisco 49ers 44, Los Angeles Raiders 14 -- Box Score", 
"Seattle Seahawks 28, Washington Redskins 7 -- Box Score")

allgames_thisweek[1]
"Chicago Bears 21, Tampa Bay Buccaneers 9 -- Box Score"
```

Each row has the following data [team1, team1score, team2, team2score, --, Box Score]

My data is all formatted the exact same way, meaning there's always a comma after the first team's score, and there's always a -- after the 2nd team's score. I'd like to create a dataframe that has 4 columns (team1, team1score, team2, team2score), so an output might look like this:

```
output_df
            team1    team1score                  team2   team2score
1.  Chicago Bears            21  Tampba Bay Buccaneers            9
```

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this? Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: something like this - unlist(strsplit(allgames_thisweek[1], ',|--')) turns the string into 3 strings, which is a good start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` + `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

string %>%
  str_replace("(?<=\\d)\\s.*--.+$", "") %>%
  str_replace_all("\\s(?=\\d+\\b)", ",") %>%
  strsplit(",") %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("team1", "team1score", "team2", "team2score"))
```

**Result:**

```
                 team1 team1score                 team2 team2score
1        Chicago Bears         21  Tampa Bay Buccaneers          9
2     Cleveland Browns         28    Cincinnati Bengals         20
3       Dallas Cowboys         26   Pittsburgh Steelers          9
4        Detroit Lions         31       Atlanta Falcons         28
5    Green Bay Packers         16     Minnesota Vikings         10
6   Indianapolis Colts         45        Houston Oilers         21
7   Kansas City Chiefs         30    New Orleans Saints         17
8     Los Angeles Rams         14     Arizona Cardinals         12
9       Miami Dolphins         39  New England Patriots         35
10     New York Giants         28   Philadelphia Eagles         23
11       New York Jets         23         Buffalo Bills          3
12  San Diego Chargers         37        Denver Broncos         34
13 San Francisco 49ers         44   Los Angeles Raiders         14
14    Seattle Seahawks         28   Washington Redskins          7
```

**Notes:**

1. `(?<=\\d)\\s.*--.+$` matches a space (`\\s`) followed by any character *zero or more times* (`.*`), the literal `--`, any character *one or more times* (`.+`), and which ends the string (`$`). This pattern has an extra condition that it has to be following a digit `(?<=\\d)`.
2. `(?<=...)` is called a positive lookbehind, which checks whether what comes *after* is immediately following the pattern in `...`.
3. `\\s(?=\\d+\\b)` matches a space that immediately follows (`(?=...)`) a digit *one or more times* and a word boundary (`\\b`). So this matches the space between the team names and the team scores.
4. `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead, which checks whether what comes *before* immediately follows the pattern in `...`.

**Data:**

```
string = c("Chicago Bears 21, Tampa Bay Buccaneers 9 -- Box Score", "Cleveland Browns 28, Cincinnati Bengals 20 -- Box Score", 
       "Dallas Cowboys 26, Pittsburgh Steelers 9 -- Box Score", "Detroit Lions 31, Atlanta Falcons 28 (OT)  -- Box Score", 
       "Green Bay Packers 16, Minnesota Vikings 10 -- Box Score", "Indianapolis Colts 45, Houston Oilers 21 -- Box Score", 
       "Kansas City Chiefs 30, New Orleans Saints 17 -- Box Score", 
       "Los Angeles Rams 14, Arizona Cardinals 12 -- Box Score", "Miami Dolphins 39, New England Patriots 35 -- Box Score", 
       "New York Giants 28, Philadelphia Eagles 23 -- Box Score", "New York Jets 23, Buffalo Bills 3 -- Box Score", 
       "San Diego Chargers 37, Denver Broncos 34 -- Box Score", "San Francisco 49ers 44, Los Angeles Raiders 14 -- Box Score", 
       "Seattle Seahawks 28, Washington Redskins 7 -- Box Score")
```

Comment: where can i learn more about the use of parameters like "(?<=\\d)\\s.*--.+$" inside of str_replace() - i've seen these used before for funcitons like grepl, but not sure how they work

Comment: @Canovice Added some explanation for the regex. Hope this helps!

Comment: They are called regular expressions. [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)

Comment: @Canovice lookbehinds and lookaheads are part of "PERL regular expressions". Maybe searching with this term would help.